# Retrieve Project Name

Tags: rally

How do you get the project name in Rally?

I'm working with a grid app and all I'm trying to do is include a 'Project' field for the grid view. However, because 'Project' is actually an object, the resulting field is '[object Object]'. So, how is it possible to get the name in string type?

Here's the code from my columnCfgs that deals with making the field.

`{
    text: 'Project',
    dataIndex: this.getContext().getProject().get
},`

Answer (score 1):

Try `this.getContext().getProject()._refObjectName` or `this.getContext().getProject().Name`

In some cases it is useful to print and explore the object in the console, because it may be that you need to traverse `project.data._refObjectName` as in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/nmusaelian-rally/126f2175f1b22870fa16), or in your case:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', {
    extend: 'Rally.app.App',
    componentCls: 'app',
    items:{ html:'<a href="https://help.rallydev.com/apps/2.0/doc/">App SDK 2.0 Docs</a>'},
    launch: function() {
        var currentProject = this.getContext().getProject();
        console.log(currentProject);
        this.add({
            xtype:'container',
            html: currentProject.Name
        });

    }
});
```

[image]

Comment: Okay so this works for getting the current/selected project, but what about if I wanted to see the Project name associated with a particular defect? For example, when I run the code from above, the console logs the name of the project I am currently on, but I want to see the project that a defect in the grid is associated with instead. These methods seem to not work in this scenario.

Comment: You are correct, this works for this.getContext().getProject().get - the question you asked. A Project attribute on a Defect is a reference to a full object, but you get only the reference. That's not specific to AppSDK, that's general for WS API v2.0. To get the full Project object you will need to hydrate it in a separate request, and fetch fields that are otherwise not available in the reference. But if all you need is name, just use _refObjectName